# How to load external file with parameters

Tags: node.js, request, inject, nightmare

So I'm creating a script that uses nightmareJS and requests. I'm making the requests grab data from a webpage and then have nightmareJS navigate to a page as well. I'm then injecting a javascript file into the nightmare session using

```
.inject('js', 'injectFile.js')
```

This all works perfectly, however im trying to achieve something else. After grabbing data from the other page using requests, i would like to pass that data into the injectFile.js file. For example, I would get a url with the request. and then use that url in the injectFile.js file when it is called. Is there anyway / module to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to define a function in `injectFile.js`, so that whatever you're doing doesn't run immediately when you inject the file, but only when you call the function:

```
function doStuff(params) {
  // do stuff with params
  // (this probably contains your entire injectFile.js script)
}
```

Then use `nightmare.evaluate` to call that function after you have injected it into the browser context:

```
nightmare.evaluate(function(params) {
  doStuff(params);
}, yourFavoriteParamValues)
```